# Only Unzip .csv files in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a backup zipped file that has hundreds of files in it. Unzipping ALL the files takes over an hour to process.

Is there a way to ONLY unzip the .csv files in Azure Data Factory?

Comment: Could you provide your approach and did you get any error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My research concluded it is not possible. We ended up using a python script in databricks to perform the activity of only unzipping the .csv files.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding ,it is not possible specifically to unzip csv files only based on the out of the box functionality